# c# going through an int and adding every character to a sum

Tags: c#

```
while (sum != 0)
{
    n += sum % 10;
    sum /= 10;
}
```

I know what the code does, but can someone explain me how it works?

Comment: integer division truncation.

Answer (score 3):

`% 10` returns the modulo 10 (remainder after division by 10) of the integer, so that is basically the last decimal digit.

`/= 10` divides by 10. Since it's an integer division, the part after the comma is truncated, so this basically removes the last digit.

So, for a number 123, this happens;

```
n = n + 3;
sum = 123 / 10 = 12;
n = n + 2;
sum = 12 / 10 = 1;
n = n + 1;
```

So `sum` is a bad name, since it is actually the variable that contains the input and which is processed. `n` is actually the variable that contains the sum. You should initialize `n` to 0 and `sum` to the input integer to make this work properly.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a program to calculate the sum of all digits in an integer.

How it works:

It takes the remainder of the number / 10 and iteratively adds it to a variable initialised to 0.

Sequence of steps:
Suppose sum = 2155, n = 0
In the first iteration,

```
n += sum % 10; //Here, n = n+ sum % 10. So, n will be evauated to 5 since, 2155 % 10 = 5
sum /= 10; // Here, sum = sum / 10, since sum is an integer, the value of sum will now be 2155 / 10 = 215
```

This happens iteratively until value of sum becomes 0 and value of n will be 2+1+5+5 = 13.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot!

Comment: @Zaycn You're welcome!